# Orchard source version on different computer (team foundation server)

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

When installing the source Orchard on my laptop is about 450MB, while Orchard on my desktokp is over 1.3 GIG. 
I have added nothing to the Orchard (desktop) of notable size, except adding a new theme and a few modules and layout changes.

I've checked in my Orchard project on the team foundation server but cannot get it to work on my laptop.

When viewing the error list it shows nearly 500 errors (seems like i'm missing several core pieces of Orchard for some reason?).

Below are a few of the errors generated (all Orchard files).

```
The type or namespace name 'Autofac' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'FluentHibernate' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

...
```

Made the following steps on my laptop:

1. Downloaded the source version of Orchard (1.6)
2. Extracted and ran the .sln file in Visual Studio (no problems so far)
3. Signed in on the team foundation server
4. "Get latest version"
5. Errors ....

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to enable Nuget package restore so that the packages are automatically downloaded rather than being checked in with the source code. Right-click on the solution in solution explorer and select Enable Nuget Package Restore. If you fire up the Package Manager Console

> Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console

You should see an error stating that your solution has missing packages.

Comment: Hello levelnis, I think you are indeed spot on the problem! But how exactly can i know what to install it does not seem to be retrieving anything. I see no errors when running the console.

Comment: If you right-click and enable package restore and then rebuild the solution, Nuget will download the packages that it requires in the background. It looks at `packages.config` to find out what should be installed.

Comment: Hm errors increased from 480 to 734 now..
Orchard is having troubles finding many .ddl files.

Comment: Most of those will be red herrings. If an inner project won't compile, the solution will throw a bundle of errors from the projects that depend on it. Fix the inner error and the outer ones all go away too. Check that the Nuget packages have downloaded into the packages folder in Windows Explorer first and then have a look at the Project build order and start building projects one at a time until you find the culprit

Comment: Still having problems to make this to work i'm afraid. All the packages are there and they have the same version. All the errors are generated from Orchard.framework a lot of namespaces are not being found.

Comment: Was able to fix alot of errors by coping the bin/debug contents from my desktop to my laptop to fix the framework errors. But it seems the other parts of Orchard are still missing a lot of references aswel, really confusing and hard to fix. No idea what causes this.

Comment: Try copying the Modules folder across as well

Comment: The weird thing is both map structures are completely different, hence all the issues probably. My desktop has a lib and src folder where my laptop is divided withseveral maps on the same level (orchard, orchard.tests, .nuget and so on..)

Comment: Back up a step or two. So to get this straight, you checked working code into TFS from your desktop, downloaded the Orchard source onto your laptop and then did a Get Latest over the top of that? Try creating a new TFS workspace in a different local folder and Getting Latest again from scratch without getting the Orchard Source first as it should be in TFS, no?

Comment: Found the culprit quite silly though. The project I retrieved from the team foundation was located in a different folder then the Orchard source version hence all the errors. Thanks for the assistance levelnis!

Comment: No worries, glad you fixed it